# VB.net Setup Issue

Tags: vb.net, mdac

While creating the setup for VB.net application I am getting the following warning:
"Warning    1   'msado15.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" is under Windows System File Protection.

Please suggest me how to over come this type of issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that file is normally already on the operating system, so it should not be necessary to install it. If you remove the user's original protected file in your app uninstall, it can cause problems on the user machine.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.

It doesn't make any sence to me. this dll is added under the EXE file dependnecy. Removing this dll from setup will cause some problem. Please suggest.

Comment: MDAC is included in the .net framework, so I don't think you should have to install it in a vb.net application. I'm not sure why it's coming up as a dependency. Maybe there's a declaration in the application that is from an older version.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of IDE components not talking to each other.

- One component says "you reference `msado15.dll` in your code, therefore I should include it in the project".
- An unrelated component says "`msado15.dll` is on my list of protected DLLs, therefore I should warn you not to include it".
- However, no component thinks like a human and says "hang on, this DLL is part of the framework, therefore I should silently remove it from the installer".

It's up to you to do the last part yourself.